# Is there a way to combine a python module in one file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way to combine all python files in a module in one file.

For example, how to combine all files of this package structure :

```
sound/
    __init__.py
    formats/
        __init__.py
        wavread.py
        wavwrite.py
        ...
    effects/
        __init__.py
        echo.py
        surround.py
        ...
```

Into one file `sound.py` ?

> I'm trying with [redbaron](https://redbaron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but this is not easy

Comment: One module is one file anyways. Do you want to combine all files of a package into one single file?

Comment: use `__all__` and import it into the `sound.__init__.py` file, or am I oversimplifying this?

Comment: Show us what you've written so far, together with a **simple** example (perhaps just wav{read,write}.py) depicting what goes wrong.

Comment: Yes @SupratimHaldar, I'd like to find a way to combine all files of a package into one single file

Comment: @J_H : I'm writing code for website https://www.codingame.com, but GUI only accept a single file with all code and sometimes this file use more than 100KB. I'd like to structure code in a package and generate a single file when I finished

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if there exists a generic and automated way to achieve this. I think it will all depend on the type of that exist in each file - class definition, utility functions and so on. If number of files is not too large, then you can do it manually. Else you can write a script to loop through all directories, read each file and append the content in a new file. However, you have to take care of all imports afterwards.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Read again the last line of zen of python.